# Is This a Good Design for Creating Thread-Safe Classes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Often, when I want a class which is thread-safe, I do something like the following:

```
public class ThreadSafeClass
{
    private readonly object theLock = new object();

    private double propertyA;
    public double PropertyA
    {
        get
        {
            lock (theLock)
            {
                return propertyA;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (theLock)
            {
                propertyA = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private double propertyB;
    public double PropertyB
    {
        get
        {
            lock (theLock)
            {
                return propertyB;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (theLock)
            {
                propertyB = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        lock (theLock)
        {
            PropertyA = 2.0 * PropertyB;
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but it is very verbose.  Sometimes I even create a lock object for each method and property creating more verbosity and complexity.

I know that it is also possible to lock classes using the Synchronization attribute but I'm not sure how well that scales -- as I often expect to have hundreds of thousands, if not millions, of instances of thread-safe objects.  This approach would create a synchronization context for every instance of the class, and requires the class to be derived from ContextBoundObject and therefore could not be derived from anything else -- since C# doesn't allow for multiple inheritance -- which is a show stopper in many cases.

Edit: As several of the responders have emphasized, there is no "silver bullet" thread-safe class design.  I'm just trying to understand if the pattern I'm using is one of the good solutions.  Of course the best solution in any particular situation is problem dependent.  Several of the answers below contain alternative designs which should be considered.

Edit: Moreover, there is more than one definition of thread safety.  For example, in my implementation above, the following code would NOT be thread-safe:

```
var myObject = new ThreadSafeClass();
myObject.PropertyA++; // NOT thread-safe
```

So, does the class definition above represent a good approach?  If not, what would you recommend for a design with similar behavior which would be thread-safe for a similar set of uses?

Comment: Please search first: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=What+is+the+Best+Practice+for+Creating+Thread-Safe+Classes+in+C%23

Comment: Hm.  In your code, you use the same lock object for reading both PropertyA and PropertyB.  That means one thread reading PropertyA will lock out another trying to read PropertyB until the first thread is complete.  Is that what you want?  If this were my class, I'd create a separate read locker for each getter and then the setters must also respect that lock.  See an answer below.

Comment: I just downvoted you because there is no single way to produce a thread-safe class. Any answer to this question risks giving the wrong impression to future readers.

Comment: John, I agree with you and have edited my question above following your comment.

Comment: My point was not that there is more than one _solution_ - my point is that there is more than one _definition_ of thread-safe. Your question suggests there is only one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no "one-size-fits-all" solution to the multi-threading problem. Do some research on creating immutable classes and learn about the different synchronization primitives.

This is an example of a **semi-immutable** or **the-programmers-immutable** class .

```
public class ThreadSafeClass
{
    public double A { get; private set; }
    public double B { get; private set; }
    public double C { get; private set; }

    public ThreadSafeClass(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
    }

    public ThreadSafeClass RecalculateA()
    {
        return new ThreadSafeClass(2.0 * B, B, C);
    }
}
```

This example moves your synchronization code into another class and serializes access to an instance. In reality, you don't really want more than one thread operating on an object at any given time.

```
public class ThreadSafeClass
{
    public double PropertyA { get; set; }
    public double PropertyB { get; set; }
    public double PropertyC { get; set; }

    private ThreadSafeClass()
    {

    }

    public void ModifyClass()
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    public class Synchronizer
    {
        private ThreadSafeClass instance = new ThreadSafeClass();
        private readonly object locker = new object();

        public void Execute(Action<ThreadSafeClass> action)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                action(instance);
            }
        }

        public T Execute<T>(Func<ThreadSafeClass, T> func)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                return func(instance);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a quick example of how you would use it. It may seem a little clunky but it allows you to execute many actions on the instance in one go.

```
var syn = new ThreadSafeClass.Synchronizer();

syn.Execute(inst => { 
    inst.PropertyA = 2.0;
    inst.PropertyB = 2.0;
    inst.PropertyC = 2.0;
});

var a = syn.Execute<double>(inst => {
    return inst.PropertyA + inst.PropertyB;
});
```

Comment: I understand your approach here -- and I see that in many cases it would be the best one.  However, it does not allow A, B, and C to be changed with the property syntax, and will create performance problems if updates are very frequent since each update entails creating a new object and letting the GC handle the old one.

Comment: Well not for a class like this. But for any kind business object you are correct.

Comment: This is just an example of an immutable class. While it's technically correct to say that it's "thread safe" (in the sense that interactions with multiple simultaneous threads won't cause corruption or misbehavior) it's hardly a model for "this is how all 'thread-safe' classes should be made".

Comment: There is no "one-size-fits-all" model for thread-safe classes. This and my update are two of many possibilities.

Comment: My sympathies. I was going to give you +1 anyway but I feel a greater urge since you've been hit by those hoodlums.

Comment: @Chaos: There definitely isn't, but without that clarification as part of your answer you seem to be implying that immutability is the go-to strategy for dealing with thread safety.

Comment: @Platinum Azure - Thanks, we'll clean up these streets someday.

Comment: @Adam Robinson - I added some clarification.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: A nitpick... Strictly speaking your "immutable" class isn't immutable. The private setters will prevent external code from directly mutating an instance, but there's nothing to stop mutations from within the class itself. For proper immutability you'd need to use `readonly` backing fields and only provide property setters, not getters. (Having said all that, I use this semi-immutable pattern quite often myself when I'm feeling lazy.)

Comment: @Luke - **lazy** being the key word here. :)

Comment: +1: immutable classes really are the best general purpose solution to thread-safe classes, especially if you just want to write the class and don't even want to think about whether you've implemented thread safety correctly.

Comment: @Joe: "However, it does not allow A, B, and C to be changed with the property syntax, and will create performance problems" -- I personally don't buy this argument. For a start, very fine-grained locks can be a performance killer in and of themselves. Additionally, modifying your object requires the creation of a single new object -- a very tiny overhead in .NET languages. Odds are, you already create 10s of 1000s of short-lived objects in your methods already, I wouldn't imagine this class adding a few microseconds to your programs runtime.

Answer (score 4):

I know this might sound like an smart a** answer but ... the BEST way to develop threadsafe classes is to actually know about multithreading, about its implications, its intricacies and what does it implies. There's no silver bullet.

- First [you need a good reason to use it](http://www.theserverside.net/blogs/thread.tss?thread_id=44945). Threads are a tool, you don't want to hit everything with your new found hammer.
- Secondly, learn about the problems of multithreading... [deadlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), [starvation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_starvation) and so on
- Third, make sure is worth it. I'm talking about benefit/cost.
- Finally... be prepared to heavy debugging. [Debugging multithreaded code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164746.aspx) is much more difficult than standard old sequential code. Learn some techniques about how to do that.

Seriously... don't try to multithread (in production scenarios I mean) until you know what you're getting yourself into... It can be a huge mistake.

**Edit:** You should of course know the synchronization primitives of both the operating system and your language of choice (C# under Windows in this case, I guess).

I'm sorry I'm not giving just the code to just make a class threadsafe. That's because it **does not exist**. A completely threadsafe class will probably just be slower than just avoiding threads and will probably act as a bottleneck to whatever you're doing... effectively undoing whatever you thing you're achieving by using threads.

Comment: I know there is no silver bullet. I have lots of production code using the pattern I described above -- and I agree with you that multi-threading should not be taken lightly. However, my application is robust and does not (currently) suffer from any deadlocks or race conditions -- although it has in the past. I'm not saying this pattern or variations on it are the answer to all multi-threading problem. I'm just asking if there is a more elegant way to get the behavior that the above code has. It never seemed ideal to me and I am trying to draw on the intelligence of the community.

Comment: I have to say that's pretty bad advice. It is like saying that one should become a master craftsman before every picking up a saw. You have to start somewhere, and this isn't a bad place.

Comment: I have to agree with Jonathan on this.

Comment: I think the part above the **Edit:** is very good general advice, because multithreading can be *deceptively* complex.  To @JonathanAllen's analogy, I'd say it's more like, "learn about kickback and tear out before using that saw to make actual furniture".

Comment: I clearly state don't try to do it on production scenarios without proper knowledge. Multithreading is one of the most complex topics (together with encryption) in the development world, the analogy is more suited against surgery. Before you do surgery on a real patient you better have a real good understanding of everything that there's to know or you'll end up killing your patient (your project). Sure, go ahead and practice on corpses to learn (do fun projects to learn) but don't do it on production code if you don't have the proper knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind that the term "thread safe" is not specific; what you're doing here would be more accurately referred to as "synchronization" through the use of a `Monitor` lock.

That said, the verbosity around synchronized code is pretty much unavoidable. You could cut down on some of the whitespace in your example by turning things like this:

```
lock (theLock)
{
    propertyB = value;
}
```

into this:

```
lock (theLock) propertyB = value;
```

As to whether or not this is the *right* approach for you we really need more information. Synchronization is just one approach to "thread safety"; immutable objects, semaphores, etc. are all different mechanisms that fit different use-cases. For the simple example you provide (where it looks like you're trying to ensure the atomicity of a get or set operation), then it looks like you've done the right things, but if your code is intended to be more of an illustration than an example then things may not be as simple.

Answer (score 3):

Since no else seems to be doing it, here is some analysis on your specific design.

- Want to read any single property? Threadsafe
- Want to update to any single property? Threadsafe
- Want to read a single property and then update it based on its original value? Not Threadsafe

Thread 2 could update the value between thread 1's read and update.

- Want to update two related properties at the same time? Not Threadsafe

You could end up with Property A having thread 1's value and Property B having thread 2's value.

1. Thread 1 Update A
2. Thread 2 Update A
3. Thread 1 Update B
4. Thread 2 Update B

   - Want to read two related properties at the same time? Not Threadsafe

Again, you could be interrupted between the first and second read.

I could continue, but you get the idea. Threadsafety is purely based on how you plan to access the objects and what promises you need to make.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked_members(VS.71).aspx) class helpful.  It contains several atomic operations.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do that could help you avoid the extra code is use something like PostSharp to automatically inject those `lock` statements into your code, even if you had hundreds of them. All you'd need is one attribute attached to the class, and the attribute's implementation which would add the extra locking variables.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above - it gets a little hairier if you want simultaneous readers allowed but only one writer allowed.  Note, if you have .NET 3.5, use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` rather than `ReaderWriterLock` for this type of pattern.

```
public class ThreadSafeClass
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLock theLock = new ReaderWriterLock();

    private double propertyA;
    public double PropertyA
    {
        get
        {
            theLock.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.Infinite);
            try
            {
                return propertyA;
            }
            finally
            {
                theLock.ReleaseReaderLock();
            }
        }
        set
        {
            theLock.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.Infinite);
            try
            {
                propertyA = value;
            }
            finally
            {
                theLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
            }
        }
    }

    private double propertyB;
    public double PropertyB
    {
        get
        {
            theLock.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.Infinite);
            try
            {
                return propertyB;
            }
            finally
            {
                theLock.ReleaseReaderLock();
            }
        }
        set
        {
            theLock.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.Infinite);
            try
            {
                propertyB = value;
            }
            finally
            {
                theLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
            }
        }
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        theLock.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.Infinite);
        try
        {
            theLock.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.Infinite);
            try
            {
                PropertyA = 2.0 * PropertyB;
            }
            finally
            {
                theLock.ReleaseReaderLock();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            theLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you had 10 properties instead of two?!

Comment: Know your tools, the framework has ReaderWriterLockSlim to perform this kind of lock: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

Comment: This is precisely why I asked if you wanted to have properties fully sync'd together or not.  It's all based on your needs.  You trade flexibility for complexity.  Chris' suggestion of ReaderWriterLockSlim (or ReaderWriterLock if you want the HEAVYWEIGHT version) will work to serialize the writers.